# Generalized Reduced Gradient algorithm in Plain English?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I'm fascinated by the results of GRG, I've managed to acquire articles and papers about it, but I can't quite grasp it, and picture it in my mind.

I thought someone who already understands could give me a small headstart from which to grok it.

Thanks for reading.